# Implement HTTP Cache (ETag) in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am working on ASP.NET Core (ASP.NET 5) Web API application and have to implement HTTP Caching with the help of Entity Tags. Earlier I used CacheCow for the same but it seems it does not support ASP.NET Core as of now. I also didn't find any other relevant library or framework support details for the same.

I can write custom code for the same but before that I want to see if anything is already available. Kindly share if something is already available and what is the better way to implement that.

Comment: according to [this](http://blog.lesierse.com/2015/12/20/cache-busting-using-aspnet5.html) etags are implemented for static files if app.UseStaticFiles() is used.

Comment: FYI CacheCow has support ASP.NET Core now.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

After a while trying to make it work with middleware I figured out that [MVC action filters](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/filters.html#action-filters) are actually better suited for this functionality.

```cs
public class ETagFilter : Attribute, IActionFilter
{
    private readonly int[] _statusCodes;

    public ETagFilter(params int[] statusCodes)
    {
        _statusCodes = statusCodes;
        if (statusCodes.Length == 0) _statusCodes = new[] { 200 };
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Method == "GET")
        {
            if (_statusCodes.Contains(context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode))
            {
                //I just serialize the result to JSON, could do something less costly
                var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context.Result);

                var etag = ETagGenerator.GetETag(context.HttpContext.Request.Path.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content));

                if (context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Keys.Contains("If-None-Match") && context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["If-None-Match"].ToString() == etag)
                {
                    context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(304);
                }
                context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("ETag", new[] { etag });
            }
        }
    }        
}

// Helper class that generates the etag from a key (route) and content (response)
public static class ETagGenerator
{
    public static string GetETag(string key, byte[] contentBytes)
    {
        var keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        var combinedBytes = Combine(keyBytes, contentBytes);

        return GenerateETag(combinedBytes);
    }

    private static string GenerateETag(byte[] data)
    {
        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            var hash = md5.ComputeHash(data);
            string hex = BitConverter.ToString(hash);
            return hex.Replace("-", "");
        }            
    }

    private static byte[] Combine(byte[] a, byte[] b)
    {
        byte[] c = new byte[a.Length + b.Length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(a, 0, c, 0, a.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(b, 0, c, a.Length, b.Length);
        return c;
    }
}
```

And then use it on the actions or controllers you want as an attribute:

```cs
[HttpGet("data")]
[ETagFilter(200)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetDataFromApi()
{
}
```

The important distinction between Middleware and Filters is that your middleware can run before and after MVC middlware and can only work with HttpContext. Also once MVC starts sending the response back to the client it's too late to make any changes to it.

Filters on the other hand are a part of MVC middleware. They have access to the MVC context, with which in this case it's simpler to implement this functionality. [More on Filters](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/filters.html) and their pipeline in MVC.

Comment: just a note to people that might be thinking of using this answer for web pages, (instead of an api). it doesn't appear to account for changes to view files.

Comment: Doesn't executing this action AFTER the endpoint has executed negated the major benefit of not having to serialise the result?  i.e. one benefit of detecting that you can return a 304 is that you can immediately stop any further server processing and just return 304.

Comment: @oatsoda yes, you're right. The main benefit here is that we don't waste clients bandwith. But the server still does all the processing it would do otherwise. Ideally the server would cache responses in some key-value structure, where key would be the etag. I have done something like that, but it's not a completely generic solution.
If I manage to do it in a way that's generic enough for a SO anwser I might post it here.

Comment: @erikbozic Yeah, I guess there are two parts 1) time taken to read/calc current etag - and then 2) time taken to serialise response.  I was thinking that you'd at least want to prevent #2 as it's redundant if you return 304!  #1 isn't strictly redundant but could be optimised!

Comment: @oatsoda just to clarify: this implementation relies on the serialized response to generate the etag. That's why it's **after** the endpoint executed. You have to generate it before you can decide to return 304. If there was actual server-side caching involved then you could check the etag value sent in the request with the cached one before executing the endpoint and just return the 304 if they match. But the server-side cache is very specific to the application (is the key just the url, additional tenant-id header, cached per user, ...?)

Comment: @erikbozic Ah yes, I see - thanks - I may have been conflating the other answer which uses an interface to allow each entity to provide an Etag value.

Comment: Although this is a good starting point, this implementation isn't handling so-called conditional requests (with `If-None-Match` and `If-Modified-Since` headers), which basically makes it incomplete. It also makes the mistake of relying on `Response.StatusCode` inside `OnActionExecuted`, while [that's always going to be 200](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45640253/7734384); among other issues.

If someone is looking for a possibly more robust implementation, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76151167/7734384).

Answer (score 5):

Building on [Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40455004/3880), I would use an interface that could be implemented on an entity to support entity tagging. In the filter you would only add the ETag if the action is returning a entity with this interface.

This allows you to be more selective about what entities get tagged and allows you have each entity control how its tag is generated. This would be much more efficient than serializing everything and creating a hash. It also eliminates the need to check the status code. It could be safely and easily added as a global filter since you are "opting-in" to the functionality by implementing the interface on your model class.

```cs
public interface IGenerateETag
{
    string GenerateETag();
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ETagFilterAttribute : Attribute, IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        if (request.Method == "GET" &&
            context.Result is ObjectResult obj &&
            obj.Value is IGenerateETag entity)
        {
            string etag = entity.GenerateETag();

            // Value should be in quotes according to the spec
            if (!etag.EndsWith("\""))
                etag = "\"" + etag +"\"";

            string ifNoneMatch = request.Headers["If-None-Match"];

            if (ifNoneMatch == etag)
            {
                context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(304);
            }

            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("ETag", etag);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, Could you show us how `GenerateETag` will works here? and should I need send json data to it?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more extensive version for MVC Views (tested with asp.net core 1.1):

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace WebApplication9.Middleware
{
    // This code is mostly here to generate the ETag from the response body and set 304 as required,
    // but it also adds the default maxage (for client) and s-maxage (for a caching proxy like Varnish) to the cache-control in the response
    //
    // note that controller actions can override this middleware behaviour as needed with [ResponseCache] attribute   
    //
    // (There is actually a Microsoft Middleware for response caching - called "ResponseCachingMiddleware", 
    // but it looks like you still have to generate the ETag yourself, which makes the MS Middleware kinda pointless in its current 1.1.0 form)
    //
    public class ResponseCacheMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        // todo load these from appsettings
        const bool ResponseCachingEnabled = true;
        const int ActionMaxAgeDefault = 600; // client cache time
        const int ActionSharedMaxAgeDefault = 259200; // caching proxy cache time 
        const string ErrorPath = "/Home/Error";

        public ResponseCacheMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        // THIS MUST BE FAST - CALLED ON EVERY REQUEST 
        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            var req = context.Request;
            var resp = context.Response;
            var is304 = false;
            string eTag = null;

            if (IsErrorPath(req))
            {
                await _next.Invoke(context);
                return;
            }


            resp.OnStarting(state =>
            {
                // add headers *before* the response has started
                AddStandardHeaders(((HttpContext)state).Response);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }, context);


            // ignore non-gets/200s (maybe allow head method?)
            if (!ResponseCachingEnabled || req.Method != HttpMethods.Get || resp.StatusCode != StatusCodes.Status200OK)
            {
                await _next.Invoke(context);
                return;
            }


            resp.OnStarting(state => {
                // add headers *before* the response has started
                var ctx = (HttpContext)state;
                AddCacheControlAndETagHeaders(ctx, eTag, is304); // intentional modified closure - values set later on
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }, context);


            using (var buffer = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // populate a stream with the current response data
                var stream = resp.Body;
                // setup response.body to point at our buffer
                resp.Body = buffer;

                try
                {
                    // call controller/middleware actions etc. to populate the response body 
                    await _next.Invoke(context);
                }
                catch
                {
                    // controller/ or other middleware threw an exception, copy back and rethrow
                    buffer.CopyTo(stream);
                    resp.Body = stream;  // looks weird, but required to keep the stream writable in edge cases like exceptions in other middleware
                    throw;
                }



                using (var bufferReader = new StreamReader(buffer))
                {
                    // reset the buffer and read the entire body to generate the eTag
                    buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    var body = bufferReader.ReadToEnd();
                    eTag = GenerateETag(req, body);


                    if (req.Headers[HeaderNames.IfNoneMatch] == eTag)
                    {
                        is304 = true; // we don't set the headers here, so set flag
                    }
                    else if ( // we're not the only code in the stack that can set a status code, so check if we should output anything
                        resp.StatusCode != StatusCodes.Status204NoContent &&
                        resp.StatusCode != StatusCodes.Status205ResetContent &&
                        resp.StatusCode != StatusCodes.Status304NotModified)
                    {
                        // reset buffer and copy back to response body
                        buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        buffer.CopyTo(stream);
                        resp.Body = stream; // looks weird, but required to keep the stream writable in edge cases like exceptions in other middleware
                    }
                }

            }
        }


        private static void AddStandardHeaders(HttpResponse resp)
        {
            resp.Headers.Add("X-App", "MyAppName");
            resp.Headers.Add("X-MachineName", Environment.MachineName);
        }


        private static string GenerateETag(HttpRequest req, string body)
        {
            // TODO: consider supporting VaryBy header in key? (not required atm in this app)
            var combinedKey = req.GetDisplayUrl() + body;
            var combinedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(combinedKey);

            using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
            {
                var hash = md5.ComputeHash(combinedBytes);
                var hex = BitConverter.ToString(hash);
                return hex.Replace("-", "");
            }
        }


        private static void AddCacheControlAndETagHeaders(HttpContext ctx, string eTag, bool is304)
        {
            var req = ctx.Request;
            var resp = ctx.Response;

            // use defaults for 404s etc.
            if (IsErrorPath(req))
            {
                return;
            }

            if (is304)
            {
                // this will blank response body as well as setting the status header
                resp.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status304NotModified;
            }

            // check cache-control not already set - so that controller actions can override caching 
            // behaviour with [ResponseCache] attribute
            // (also see StaticFileOptions)
            var cc = resp.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl ?? new CacheControlHeaderValue();
            if (cc.NoCache || cc.NoStore)
                return;

            // sidenote - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232#section-4.1
            // the server generating a 304 response MUST generate any of the following header 
            // fields that WOULD have been sent in a 200(OK) response to the same 
            // request: Cache-Control, Content-Location, Date, ETag, Expires, and Vary.
            // so we must set cache-control headers for 200s OR 304s

            cc.MaxAge = cc.MaxAge ?? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ActionMaxAgeDefault); // for client
            cc.SharedMaxAge = cc.SharedMaxAge ?? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ActionSharedMaxAgeDefault); // for caching proxy e.g. varnish/nginx
            resp.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl = cc; // assign back to pick up changes

            resp.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.ETag, eTag);
        }

        private static bool IsErrorPath(HttpRequest request)
        {
            return request.Path.StartsWithSegments(ErrorPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using a middleware that works fine for me.

It adds HttpCache headers to responses (Cache-Control, Expires, ETag, Last-Modified), and implements cache expiration & validation models.

You can find it on nuget.org as a package called **Marvin.Cache.Headers**.

You could find more information from its Github home page:
https://github.com/KevinDockx/HttpCacheHeaders

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.

Comment: @herrbischoff, I added more details to my answer, hope it is better now.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to [Erik Božič's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40455004/8099205) I found that the HttpContext object was not reporting back the StatusCode correctly when inheriting from ActionFilterAttribute, and applied controller-wide. HttpContext.Response.StatusCode was always 200, indicating it was probably not set by this point in the pipeline. I was instead able to grab the StatusCode from ActionExecutedContext context.Result.StatusCode.

Comment: An addendum is better suited as a comment.

Comment: @ToothlessRebel tried that first, too little rep :(

Comment: That is a not a valid reason to circumvent the system in place and post a comment as an answer.

Comment: @cagefree Did you have this issue only when you applied to the entire controller, and not the individual rest endpoints? I will edit Erik's answer to feature your answer if you give me this information.

Comment: Although somewhat late (and on a different version of asp.net core), I tried this now and works fine for me. Maybe there something else in your request pipeline that affects this? Can you still repro?
My working example is just a new API project with the code I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution which is "closer" to the web api controller method - so you can decide per method which ETag to set...

See my response here: [How to use ETag in Web API using action filter along with HttpResponseMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145140/how-to-use-etag-in-web-api-using-action-filter-along-with-httpresponsemessage/47547988#47547988)

Answer (score 0):

We can write simple extension method on ControllerBase class

```cs
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    
    namespace WebApiUtils.Caching
    {
        public static class ExtensionMethods
        {
            public static IActionResult OkOr304<T>(
                this ControllerBase controller,
                T resultObject,
                Func<T, string> etagBuilder
            )
            {
                var etag = etagBuilder(resultObject);
    
                if (
                    // Add additional headers if needed
                    controller.Request.Headers.Keys.Contains("If-None-Match")
                    && controller.Request.Headers["If-None-Match"].ToString() == etag
                )
                {
                    return controller.StatusCode(304);
                }
    
                controller.Response.Headers.Add("ETag", new[] { etag });
    
                return controller.Ok(resultObject);
            }
    
            public static IActionResult OkOr304<T>(this ControllerBase controller, T resultObject)
            {
                return controller.OkOr304(
                    resultObject,
                    x =>
                    {
                        // Implement default ETag strategy
                        return "";
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

Then we can use it inside controller with

```cs
return this.OkOr304(resultObject, etagBuilder);
```

or

```cs
return this.OkOr304(resultObject);
```

this works very well if result objects have some version indicator e.g.

```cs
return this.OkOr304(resultObject, x => x.VersionNumber.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

### Most robust implementation (ASP.NET Core 5.0+):

The following is a more robust and reliable implementation of this, as a result filter rather than an action filter.

Here are the advantages that this solution provides over the accepted answer's:

- The status code isn't reported correctly in an action filter. The value of `context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode` is always going to be 200 in the `OnActionExecuted` method, even if the action method returned a `NotFound()`, for example. See [this answer on this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45640253/7734384), and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50463634/actionfilter-response-statuscode-is-always-200) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371900/get-httpstatus-code-from-iactionfilter-in-net-core-2-0).
- Use of [typed headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.headerdictionarytypeextensions.gettypedheaders?view=aspnetcore-3.1), making the inspection of the HTTP headers more reliable than the simple string comparisons the accepted answer's action filter is doing.
- No JSON serialization — an expensive operation that's completely unnecessary, and it also won't work at all for action methods that return anything other than objects (e.g. files, etc.)
- There's no need to include the request path as part of the ETag calculation, ETags are fundamentally bound to the "resource" (i.e. request URI) they belong to anyway.
- Support for conditional requests and the `If-Modified-Since` and `If-None-Match` request headers, without which the implementation is incomplete. Why would you even bother sending an `ETag` to the client if you're not going to actually handle the conditional requests that the client will later send (with `If-None-Match`)?!

```cs
public class HandleHttpCachingAttribute : ResultFilterAttribute
{
    // NOTE: When a "304 Not Modified" response is to be sent back to the client, all headers apart from the following list should be stripped from the response to keep the response size minimal. See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7232#section-4.1:~:text=200%20(OK)%20response.-,The%20server%20generating%20a%20304,-response%20MUST%20generate
    private static readonly string[] _headersToKeepFor304 = {
        HeaderNames.CacheControl,
        HeaderNames.ContentLocation,
        HeaderNames.ETag,
        HeaderNames.Expires,
        HeaderNames.Vary,
        // NOTE: We don't need to include `Date` here — even though it is one of the headers that should be kept — because `Date` will always be included in every response anyway.
    };

    public override async Task OnResultExecutionAsync(
        ResultExecutingContext context,
        ResultExecutionDelegate next
    )
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        // NOTE: For more info on this technique, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65901913 and https://www.madskristensen.net/blog/send-etag-headers-in-aspnet-core/ and https://gist.github.com/madskristensen/36357b1df9ddbfd123162cd4201124c4
        var originalStream = response.Body; // NOTE: This specific `Stream` object is what ASP.NET Core will eventually read and send to the client in the response body.
        using MemoryStream memoryStream = new();

        response.Body = memoryStream;
        await next();
        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        // NOTE: We only work with responses that have a status code of 200.
        if (response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status200OK)
        {
            var requestHeaders = request.GetTypedHeaders();
            var responseHeaders = response.GetTypedHeaders();

            responseHeaders.CacheControl = new()
            {
                Public = true,
                MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365), // NOTE: One year is one of the most common values for the `max-age` directive of `Cache-Control`. It's typically used for resources that are immutable (never change) and can therefore be cached indefinitely. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25201898
            };
            responseHeaders.ETag ??= GenerateETag(memoryStream); // NOTE: We calculate an ETag based on the body of the request, if some later middleware hasn't already set one.

            if (IsClientCacheValid(requestHeaders, responseHeaders))
            {
                response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status304NotModified;

                // NOTE: Remove all unnecessary headers while only keeping the ones that should be included in a `304` response.
                foreach (var header in response.Headers)
                    if (!_headersToKeepFor304.Contains(header.Key))
                        response.Headers.Remove(header.Key);

                return;
            }
        }

        await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(originalStream); // NOTE: Writes anything the later middleware wrote to the the body (and by extension our `memoryStream`) to the original response body stream, so that it will be sent back to the client as the response body.
    }

    private static EntityTagHeaderValue GenerateETag(Stream stream)
    {
        byte[] hashBytes = MD5.HashData(stream); // NOTE: MD5 is still suitable for use cases like this one, even though it's "cryptographically broken". It's pretty commonly used for generating ETags.
        stream.Position = 0; // NOTE: Reset the position to 0 so that the calling code can still read the stream.
        string hashString = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes); // NOTE: We choose base64 instead of hex because it'd be shorter, since the character set is larger.
        return new('"' + hashString + '"'); // NOTE: An `ETag` needs to be surrounded by quotes. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag#:~:text=It%20is%20a%20string%20of%20ASCII%20characters%20placed%20between%20double%20quotes
    }

    private static bool IsClientCacheValid(RequestHeaders reqHeaders, ResponseHeaders resHeaders)
    {
        // NOTE: If both `If-None-Match` and `If-Modified-Since` are present in a request, `If-None-Match` takes precedence and `If-Modified-Since` is ignored (provided, of course, that the resource supports entity-tags, hence the second condition after the `&&` operator in the following `if`). See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7232#section-3.3:~:text=A%20recipient%20MUST%20ignore%20If%2DModified%2DSince%20if
        // NOTE: Therefore, we put the condition that checks if `If-None-Match` exists first.
        if (reqHeaders.IfNoneMatch.Any() && resHeaders.ETag is not null)
            return reqHeaders.IfNoneMatch.Any(etag =>
                etag.Compare(resHeaders.ETag, useStrongComparison: false) // NOTE: We shouldn't use `Contains` here because it would use the `Equals` method which apparently shouldn't be used for ETag equality checks. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.net.http.headers.entitytagheadervalue.equals?view=aspnetcore-7.0. We also use weak comparison, because that seems to what the built-in response caching middleware (which is general-purpose enough in this particular respect to be able to inform us here) is doing. See https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/7f4ee4ac2fc945eab33d004581e7b633bdceb475/src/Middleware/ResponseCaching/src/ResponseCachingMiddleware.cs#LL449C51-L449C70
            );

        if (reqHeaders.IfModifiedSince is not null && resHeaders.LastModified is not null)
            return reqHeaders.IfModifiedSince >= resHeaders.LastModified;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage — in `FooController.c`:

```cs
[HandleHttpCaching]
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{

}
```