# How to add a ETag header in response generated by CreatedAtAction function?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Say I have a Controller with *HTTP POST* and *HTTP GET* defined such as

```
[HttpGet]
[ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string id, CancellationToken cancellation = default(CancellationToken))
{
    //Some asyc code to retrieve ret...
    return new ObjectResult(ret);
```

}

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(string someContent, CancellationToken cancellation = default(CancellationToken))
{
    //Some async code...
    //How could I have ETag also appear in the headers or should I
    //return the version number of the created resource explicitly in the
    //return type?
    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new { Id = "someId" }, "ResultResult");
}
```

All good and well, it's working, but I wonder how could I add the version of the created resource as a `ETag` header in the response? Is it possible while using `CreatedAtAction` or should one resort to other facilities?

This is different than [Implement HTTP Cache (ETag) in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458737/implement-http-cache-etag-in-asp-net-core-web-api/40455004) as I'm not looking for a middleware piece on how to match browser requests to cache, but how to add a `ETag` header to a response to a HTTP POST that in the backend resulted into creation of a resource and giving a version number to it. It is this backend generated version number I'd like to include in the response and it looks like it needs to be embedded into the result type, but I'd prefer the `ETag` header.

From discussion with Erik, I noticed a strange thing adding the ETag to the context, it's shown in the debugging visualisation text, but on in the collection. Is there something I don't notice?
[image: Strange: ETag in the debugging text, but not in the collection.]

Comment: You could use a filter like anwsered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458737/implement-http-cache-etag-in-asp-net-core-web-api/40455004#40455004

Comment: It looks like that answer is particularly on caching and checking GET requests. I'm interested on how to include the ETag header in the response (or any header for that matter) and in this particular case the version would come from the backend and should be backed into the response somehow.

Comment: As I understand it you want to add an ETag header to the response if the resource was created (or some other condition).
Why not just call `HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("ETag","your-resource-version");` in the controller if you want to add the header? 
Ofcourse you would need to get the version from somewhere - presumably from your entity, query it from database... Can give a complete anwser if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: @ErikBozic That's right! I tried that already and it almost work, see the edit. It's well past midnight here, so I'll need to sleep, but I'll check this in the morning if that's OK with you. That's rather puzzling that with the collection being empty.