# Get HttpStatus code from IActionFilter in .Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have filter attribute in ASP.NET core 2.0, See my code snippet below. Here the problem is I always get the status code is 200.

Even the actual status code is 500 then also I get a 200. How do I get the actual status code?

```
public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
{
    try
    {
        var controller = context.Controller as APIServiceBase;
        var statusCode = controller.Response.StatusCode;
        ..
        ..
    }
    catch { }

}
```

Comment: Don't have time to dig into this but have you looked at [exception or resource filters](https://damienbod.com/2015/09/30/asp-net-5-exception-filters-and-resource-filters/)? Seems like any 500 series status code would be treated as an 'exception'.

Comment: Have you considered using `IResultFilter` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite an interesting question. Action filters are executed just after the action itself. The problem is that `IActionResult` returned by the action is not yet executed at this stage. You could check it by returning your custom implementation of `IActionResult` and checking that its `ExecuteResultAsync` method is executed after `OnActionExecuted()` of the action filter .

Since response is populated by `IActionResult` (including status code), you shouldn't expect that `Response.StatusCode` will be already set in action filter.

To solve this problem you should execute your logic later in ASP.Net Core pipeline, action filter is just not a proper place for it. You could add custom middleware in request pipeline (`Startup.Configure()` method):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        await next.Invoke();
        var statusCode = context.Response.StatusCode;
        // ...
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Make sure you add it before call to `app.UseMvc()`. You could wrap delegate logic to separate class if required.

Answer (score 5):

As raised by CodeFuller, your action may not have been executed yet. 
However if you want to keep a filter-pattern to apply it only to specific methods, you may get use of the `OnCompleted` method of the response:

```
// Called on incoming request
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutedContext context)
{
    context.HttpContext.Response.OnCompleted(async () => {
        // Executed once the response is sent

        var status = context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;

        // Work here
        // Be careful on Transient or Scoped injections, they may already be disposed
        // If you need a DbContext, instanciate it by injecting 
        //    DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> earlier in the code

    });
}
```

This method should work for most types of filter, so you may use a any depending on the filter inputs you need.