# Why is there no access to context.Result.StatusCode in Action and Result filters?

Tags: c#, .net-core, action-filter

I'm trying to write an action or result filter that automatically does something if the status code is >= 400. The ActionExecutedContext.Result property looks like it should provide access to the status code:
[image]

But there is no access to the status code:
[image]

Is this by design? What's the best way to get the actual status code?

Comment: Remember, the debugger shows you details about the *concrete runtime types of objects*. The compiler wants you to work from the *declared types* of things. These aren't always the same. So an `IActionResult` doesn't necessarily have a `StatusCode` property, whilst a `BadRequestResult` instance, specifically, does.

Comment: Is this asp.net core? Turns out I kinda assumed core in my answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get HttpStatus code from IActionFilter in .Net Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371900/get-httpstatus-code-from-iactionfilter-in-net-core-2-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, the IActionResult isn't executed yet so the statuscode may potentially change. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49376929/4364057) basically has the answer to this problem: Make a middleware and let that check the status code.

Answer (score -1):

In this case you should look to the response status code.

> var statusCode = context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;

Here is a test just I did and it is working:

```
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var statusCode = context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;

        if (statusCode == StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)
        {
            //DO SOMETHING
        }
    }
```

On OnActionExecuted the result should already be there, but what you need seems to be more OnResultExecuted.

Comment: The last thing I wanted to do is end up with a bunch of if statements to deal with different concrete result types. Also, `context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode` is always 200, it's the default http response status.