# Conditional Http Request in ASP.Net Core and Other Http Mechanisms in Browser

Tags: asp.net-core, http, caching, http-headers, etag

I know that browser implements logic of Http Conditional Requests automatically (And also logic for CORS, Caching). What about the server-side? Does they should implement these logic and behaviours or it is developer task to implement them? Is it ever an standard for web servers which should follow for example different features they have implemented to enforce them and standardize for these types of behaviours?
What about ASP.Net core and Kestrel Web Server specifically?

Comment: Refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: @XinranShen No I mean here the requests come from client, How they handle in server? for example in case of conditional request server may return 304 Not Modified. Are these standards already implemented in ASP.Net or Developer should implement them?

Comment: Actually, Your question contains a lot of content, Asp .Net Core use MiddleWare to handle http request, You can refer to this [doc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/http-modules?view=aspnetcore-6.0),[doc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to learn more about .

Comment: Your question is a perfectly valid one. The answer is that ASP.NET Core only handles conditional requests for its static files middleware. For everything else, you need to do it on your own, or look into third-party libraries like [this](https://github.com/KevinDockx/HttpCacheHeaders) and [this](https://github.com/aliostad/CacheCow).

Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35458737) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76151167).