# Etag is not present in response header

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm traying to set Etag in response header, but when i check response header in browser i can't see it. By the way this only applies to Etag, i can see another tag and value. By the way i can see it on localhost but when i publish that code to server i cant see.
[image]

```html
 public static void InsertETag(HttpResponseBase response, Model model)
  {
  

   try
   {
  
    var eTagValue = CalculateETag(model);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eTagValue))
    {
   
     
     var matchETagValue = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["If-None-Match"];
     if (matchETagValue != null && matchETagValue == eTagValue)
     {
      response.SuppressContent = true;
      response.StatusCode = 304;
      response.StatusDescription = "Not Modified";
      response.Headers["Content-Length"] = "0";
      response.AppendHeader("ETag", eTagValue);
     }
     else
     {
      response.AppendHeader("ETag", eTagValue);
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? Are you able to use `response.Headers.ETag = new StringValues(eTagValue);`?

Comment: Hi @DavidG im using 4.8. I checked that but i'm not able this.

Comment: Have you looked at tis?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145140/how-to-use-etag-in-web-api-using-action-filter-along-with-httpresponsemessage

Answer (score 0):

From here
[How to use ETag in Web API using action filter along with HttpResponseMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145140/how-to-use-etag-in-web-api-using-action-filter-along-with-httpresponsemessage)

```
var request = context.Request;
        var key = GetKey(request);

        EntityTagHeaderValue etag;
        if (!etags.TryGetValue(key, out etag) || request.Method == HttpMethod.Put || request.Method == HttpMethod.Post)
        {
            etag = new EntityTagHeaderValue("\"" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "\"");
            etags.AddOrUpdate(key, etag, (k, val) => etag);
        }

        context.Response.Headers.ETag = etag;
        SetCacheControl(context.Response);
```